# converting superclasses and subclasses back and forth

Tags: java, inheritance

I wish to be able to change a subclass to a superclass then, if needed, back to its subclass to get access to all the methods and fields and modify them as required.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static main(String[] args) {
        SpecificEvent completeEvent = new SpecificEvent();
        GenericEvent event = completeEvent;
        event.fire();
        // without creating a new SpecificEvent how can i change str, without using the completeEvent reference, so that event.fire() has a different result?
    }
}

public abstract class GenericEvent {
    public abstract void fire();
}

public class SpecificEvent extends GenericEvent {
    public String str = "fired";
    @Override
    public void fire() {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Does the code need to be restructured?

Comment: Casting in Java essentially boils down to "converting superclasses and subclasses back and forth": `((SpecificEvent) event).str = "hello";`.  But your code will end up a mess.  Look into abstract classes and interfaces.

Comment: @Mr Spoon, Are you telling me to look into abstracts to help me refactor my code? Or as a solution to my problem?

Comment: Just as an idea to refactor it: I think casting is really what you are after here.

Comment: Edited the code to show an abstract.

Comment: Why do you use the superclass if what you really need is the subclass? You can call `fire()` on `completeEvent` directly.

Comment: because it is a simplified version of the code to explain, main() isn't a actual case but rather the logic I wish to replicate. fire() is in fact a callback in a self implemented multidimensional associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet you have `GenericEvent` as static type (the specification of what `event` is required to have) and `SpecificEvent` as dynamic type (the actual implementation):

```
//no cast needed, because SpecificEvent IS an GenericEvent
GenericEvent event = new SpecificEvent();
```

If you are assuming that `event` is a `SpecificEvent`, cast to the target type:

```
//unsafe cast, exception is thrown if event is not a SpecificEvent
SpecificEvent specEvent = (SpecificEvent) event;
```

In most cases you are going to *check* for the dynamic type first:

```
if(event instanceof SpecificEvent) {
    //safe cast
    SpecificEvent specEvent = (SpecificEvent) event;
}
```

The `instanceof` above also checks for subclasses of `SpecificEvent`. If you like to check explicitly that `event` is a `SpecificEvent` (and not possibly a *subclass* of `SpecificEvent`!), compare the class object of the dynamic type:

```
if(event.getClass() == SpecificEvent.class) {
    //safe cast
    SpecificEvent specEvent = (SpecificEvent) event;
}
```

Comment: Are there any detrimental effects of having the specification and implementation types differ? Do they not match because the specification is abstract?

Comment: It's totally fine to do declare a variable more general while using only a specific implementation. It's often used with collection types, as in: `List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();`. `List` is the abstract data type here and `ArrayList` the implementation; one could change `ArrayList` to any other List-type (e.g. `LinkedList`) at any time. In contrast, if you are using implementation-specific stuff, consider changing the static type or checking the type in an if-else cascade.

P.S.: You can think of the static type as a *view* to the actual instance.